# preg_match to find words with capitals and successive capitalized words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to match keywords in strings by filtering out only words that match the following criteria:

- words with capitals ANYWHERE in them such as "iPhone" or "camelCase"
- successive capitalized word groups such as "Pittsburgh Steelers" or "Oscar De La Hoya"
- combined above criteria like "iPhone 5" or "MIB 2" (also treating numbers as capitals)
- collapse any non characters/numbers so "O'Donnell's" would be "ODonnells" and "Wi-fi..." would be "Wifi"

Example:

```
$string = "Joe O'Donnell and Oscar De La Hoya went to a Pittsburgh Steelers game on Sunday, where Joe lost his iPhone 5, so he borrowed Oscar's iPad";

preg_match_all("/[A-Z][a-z]*/",$string,$match_words); // incorrect expression

// desired result for $match_words should be: 
// array(Joe ODonnell, Oscar De La Hoya, Pittsburgh Steelers, Sunday, Joe, iPhone 5, Oscars, iPad)
```

Thanks

Comment: does it have to be preg_match? Is a different solution also acceptable?

Comment: @BrianGlaz Sure. Whatever works. Obviously the more efficient the better.

Comment: @John efficient and bulletproof :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\b((?:[A-Z]['a-z]*\s*\d*)+)\b|\b((?:[a-z]*[A-Z]['a-z]*\s*\d*)+)\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gW9pX2/1)**

[image]

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-14]  `Joe O'Donnell `
MATCH 2
1.  [18-35] `Oscar De La Hoya `
MATCH 3
1.  [45-65] `Pittsburgh Steelers `
MATCH 4
1.  [73-79] `Sunday`
MATCH 5
1.  [87-91] `Joe `
MATCH 6
2.  [100-108]   `iPhone 5`
MATCH 7
1.  [125-133]   `Oscar's `
MATCH 8
2.  [133-137]   `iPad`
```

The regex consists of two patterns:

```
\b((?:[A-Z]['a-z]*\s*\d*)+)\b       ---> Match words like Joe O'Connels or Oscar De La Hoya
|
\b((?:[a-z]*[A-Z]['a-z]*\s*\d*)+)\b ---> Match words like iPad or iPhone
```

Btw, if you take a look at the results, it has a trailing space at the end, you could do a trim to the result to have it cleaned.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't get rid of the single quotes per my OP, but I can get rid of them pretty easy with a str_replace after the trim. Works for me. Cheers.

Comment: Just noticed when checking Daniel's answer that the match for "iPad" should actually be "Oscars iPad" (although I messed that up in my original question).

Answer (score 3):

You could first remove all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
$string2 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $string);
```

Then use `preg_split` instead of `preg_replace` to *split* the string by sequences of entirely lower-case words.

```
 $match_words = preg_split("/ ([a-z]| )+ /", $string2);
```

(If you don't mind `$string` being destroyed, you can replace `$string2` with `$string`)

This works for the example you provided, but consider how you want your program to behave with less sanitised input. For instance, `"Foo  Bar"` (two spaces) would be split into two elements whereas `"Foo Bar"` (one space) would remain as one. If you're not worried about speed, you could use another `preg_replace` to replace any sequence of whitespace with a single space.

Comment: This is real close but it strips the "i" from "iPhone" and "iPad"

Comment: Well spotted, thanks John! The expression in the `preg_spit` should be `"/ ([a-z]| )+ /"` instead of `"/ ([a-z]| )+/"`. I've edit the original post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I already accepted Fede's answer as close enough, but this does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of PHP's [ctype_lower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php) function here!

```php
<?php

$string = "Joe O'Donnell and Oscar De La Hoya went to a Pittsburgh Steelers game on Sunday, where Joe lost his iPhone 5, so he borrowed Oscar's iPad";

$words = $temp = array();

// Loop through the string after turning it into an array (by spaces)
foreach (explode(" ", $string) as $word) {
    // Check if the word is lowercase and is not a number
    if (ctype_lower($word) && !is_numeric($word)) {
        if (empty($temp)) continue; // Don't add it if there's nothing to add

        // Add the words found up until this point (from the last point) into the words array, as a string
        $words[] = implode(" ", $temp);

        // Reset the temp array so we can look for new words and continue
        $temp = array();
        continue;
    }

    // Add this word to the words array
    $temp[] = $word;
}

$words[] = implode(" ", $temp);

// Print the words that have uppercase characters
printf("<pre>%s</pre>", print_r($words, true));
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Joe O'Donnell
    [1] => Oscar De La Hoya
    [2] => Pittsburgh Steelers
    [3] => Sunday,
    [4] => Joe
    [5] => iPhone 5,
    [6] => Oscar's iPad
)
```

Comment: Thanks aelieo. Seems to be missing a match for "Oscar's iPad" however.

Comment: You're right!  I forgot to add the last loop collection after the loop finished.  I updated my post to reflect the changes that will make it work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Fede's sweet answer, this would be your new PHP code:

```
$string = "Joe O'Donnell and Oscar De La Hoya went to a Pittsburgh Steelers game on Sunday, where Joe lost his iPhone 5, so he borrowed Oscar's iPad";

preg_match_all("/\b((?:[A-Z]['a-z]*\s*\d*)+)\b|\b((?:[a-z]*[A-Z]['a-z]*\s*\d*)+)\b/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

$matches[0] would be your array of matches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Fede, Kelly and Daniel, 2 alternatives for accented languages

**Using `preg_split`**

```
$capitalized_words = preg_split("/ ([a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]| )+ /u", $string);
```

**Using `preg_match_all`**

```
//with 'u' flag 
preg_match_all("/\b((?:[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÆ]['a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*\s*\d*)+)\b|\b((?:[a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÆ]['a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*\s*\d*)+)\b/u", $string, $capitalized_words);
```

**Function using `preg_match_all` together with `trim`**

```
function get_capitalized_words($string){
    $capitalized_words=array();

    //with 'u' flag 
    preg_match_all("/\b((?:[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÆ]['a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*\s*\d*)+)\b|\b((?:[a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÆ]['a-zàèìòùáéíóúýâêîôûãñõäëïöüÿçßøåæœ]*\s*\d*)+)\b/u", $string, $matches);

    if(isset($matches[0])){
        $capitalized_words=array_map('trim',$matches[0]);
    }

    return $capitalized_words;
}
```